# Angular 2 Child Routes, Slugs, Component visibility

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

**Hello,**

that is what I currently have:

```
{ path: 'slideshows', component: SlideshowComponent,

      children:[

         { path: '', redirectTo: 'slideshow-1', pathMatch: 'full' }, 
         { path: ':id',     component: SlideshowDetailsComponent,

            children:[

              { path: '',     component: SlideDetailComponent},
              { path: ':slide_key',     component: SlideDetailComponent}
            ]
          }
      ]
  },
```

––––

**A**

```
/slideshows
```

Shows a list of Slideshows, redirects to the following routes, with the slug of the first slideshow in the list *(I haven't figured out how to do that yet dynamically, so i just hardcoded the slug by now: slideshow-1)*

––––

**B**

```
/slideshows/slideshow-1 //slideshow-1 is the slug
```

This route shows a list of Slideshows as well as a slideshow (a list of slides) which match to the provided slug

––––

**C**

```
/sldieshows/slideshow-1/slide-1
```

When this route is called, the Slideshow List and the Slideshow should disappear and only the Slide with the matching slug (slideshow-1/slide-1)
should be displayed **while maintaining the url :** `/sldieshows/slideshow-1/slide-1`

––––

**Questions:**

**1.)**
At the moment the `SlideDetailComponent` is even shown when the path is empty: `path=''`.

Is there a way to make that fragment optional ?

I tried it with `{ path: '', redirectTo: 'view', pathMatch: 'full' }`,
but I wasn't able to get rid of the `redirectTo` parameter (here in the example the word: *view*). What is the correct approach here, please?

**2.)**
How to maintain the url and how to hide parent components when using child-routes? 
Or is there a better approch for the last case (C) described above?

–––

**3.)**
How to get all route parameters ?
`this.route.params` just returns the last fragment, for example: `slide-1`

–––

Thank you very much for your time !

Comment: { path: ':id',     component: SlideshowDetailsComponent,

that's it, its just a workaround as described under ```A```

Comment: I see. I missed the single top-level route.